# Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "tag" at 'message.notification': Cannot find field

Tags: typescript, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

**Minimum reproducible code:**

```
exports.testNotification = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (data != null) {
    const message = {
      token: '<fcm_token>',
      notification: {
        title: 'Dummy title',
        body: 'Dummy body',
        tag: 'foo', // This throws runtime error. 
      },
    };

    try {
      const response = await admin
        .messaging()
        .send(message);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error sending message = ', error);
    }
  }

  return null;
});
```

I am calling this from Flutter:

```dart
var callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('testNotification');
callable.call({});
```

> Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "tag" at 'message.notification': Cannot find field.
>
> errorInfo: {
> code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
> message: `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "tag" at 'message.notification': Cannot find field.`
> },
> codePrefix: 'messaging'

If I comment out `tag` field, then I do receive a notification. So, what's wrong in the code, how to use `tag` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When sending messages, the json is composed by a general "notification" section. The "tag" property is not supported here. See [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#resource:-message) for reference.

The "tag" property is related to Android, so it should be included in the "notification" property of the Android section. See [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#androidnotification) for reference.

This is an [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#example-notification-message-with-platform-specific-delivery-options) of how a notification that includes platform specific information should be generated. In the Android config I added the "tag":

```json
{
  "message":{
     "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
     "notification":{
       "title":"Match update",
       "body":"Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
     },
     "android":{
       "ttl":"86400s",
       "notification":{
         "click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY_1",
         "tag":"foo"
       }
     },
     "apns":{
       "headers":{
         "apns-priority":"5",
       },
       "payload":{
         "aps":{
           "category":"NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
         }
       }
     },
     "webpush":{
       "headers":{
         "TTL":"86400"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Do you also know how can I do something similar in iOS? For Android, it's `tag`, what's iOS equivalent?